# A surge to burninate [surge]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I came across the tag [surge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surge) while reviewing triage questions. I came across a question, but not the normal type of questions on here - one to do with lazer eye surgery:

[image]

There's only 3 questions in the `surge` tag: one to do with lazer eye surgery and others to do with a program called Surge, which I can find no trace of on the internet.

Comment: Probably https://www.npmjs.com/package/surge

Comment: https://surge.sh/

Comment: tag renamed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surge.sh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `surge` tag refers to [Surge.sh](https://surge.sh). It is a tool for static web publishing from the command line. The tag is perfectly valid IMO and used appropiately in those two questions.

The question about eye surgery should obviously be deleted, but that doesn't make a difference for the validity of the `surge` tag itself.

Comment: If you have time fill in the tag info.

Comment: I renamed the tag to say surge.sh